# Trouble inserting value into a TEXT column with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, string-constant

I am getting an error when I try to insert an alphanumeric value into a TEXT column in a Postgres DB. This is the table definition

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgTOk.png)

This is the query I am using to insert data into the table

```
INSERT INTO sensor_data
            (
                time,
                i1, i2, i3, i4,
                i5, i6, i7, i8,
                mrt,air_temperature,
                humidity,tvoc, device_id)
        VALUES (to_timestamp(1667595922) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
                41.340000,  26.160000, 25.860000, 26.160000,
                25.900000, 25.960000, 26.720000, 25.580000,
                26.085000, 28.065536,
                 55.204773,  40.000000, 1a0032000947363339343638
            );
```

This is the error message I get

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "a0032000947363339343638"
>   LINE 12:                      55.204773,  40.000000, 1a00320009473633...

When I enter this query, it works just fine.

```
INSERT INTO sensor_data
            (
                time,
                i1, i2, i3, i4,
                i5, i6, i7, i8,
                mrt,air_temperature,
                humidity,tvoc, device_id)
        VALUES (to_timestamp(1667595922) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
                41.340000,  26.160000, 25.860000, 26.160000,
                25.900000, 25.960000, 26.720000, 25.580000,
                26.085000, 28.065536,
                 55.204773,  40.000000, 10032000947363339343638
            );
```

The only difference between the 2 queries is the device_id value. The insert fails when the value is '1a0032000947363339343638' and work fine when the value is '10032000947363339343638'.

Why would the insert fail when I try to insert '1a0032000947363339343638' even though the data type is a TEXT? And how do I get the table to accept 1a0032000947363339343638' for a device Id?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes (`'`) in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While numbers do not need to be quoted, strings must be quoted to distinguish them from other syntax and to allow for spaces.

In Postgres this must be a single quote. Other databases might allow different quoting.

```
INSERT INTO sensor_data
            (
                time,
                i1, i2, i3, i4,
                i5, i6, i7, i8,
                mrt,air_temperature,
                humidity,tvoc, device_id)
        VALUES (to_timestamp(1667595922) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
                41.340000,  26.160000, 25.860000, 26.160000,
                25.900000, 25.960000, 26.720000, 25.580000,
                26.085000, 28.065536,
                 55.204773,  40.000000, '1a0032000947363339343638'
            );
```

You can read more in the [Postgres documentation on constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).

Comment: The single quotes for string constants are defined in the SQL standard, this is nothing special to Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm specifically thinking of people who might be learning from MySQL which allows both.